# JavaScript include different headers

Tags: javascript, html

I need add different headers to html page in js, but I don't know how. In php that was easy, but now I write in Java and on html page i have only js to use. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript by “Java”? If Java, why isn’t Java included in the tags?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('header', 'value');
```

butI think the easiest way to accomplish it is to use querystring instead of HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
     ...

     // xhr is an XMLHttpRequest object
     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
}
```

I think your problem can be solved by the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I need something like include() in php. I need add different html heads depending on url.